# Can I use enable_if together with typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, enable-if, redefine

I want to define a variable for which the type depends on some condition. I want something like this:

```
typedef typename enable_if<cond, int>::type Type;
typedef typename enable_if<!cond, double>::type Type;
```

But the conpiler says I redefined the type.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

> Can I use `enable_if` together with typedef?

No you can't. [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) leaves the type undefined if the condition is false. Only if the condition is true, is the member `type` is defined;

> ```
> template< bool B, class T = void >
>  struct enable_if;
> ```
>
> If `B` is `true`, `std::enable_if` has a public member typedef type, equal to `T`; otherwise, there is no member typedef.

For the typedef to work correctly, it needs a type for both cases, when the condition is true and when it is false. `enable_if` is implemented to assist in scenarios related to SFINAE.

So then

> How can I do this?

Use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). Conditional will contain a member typedef (`type`) for both the `true` and `false` result of the condition.

> ```
> template< bool B, class T, class F >
>  struct conditional;
> ```
>
> Provides member typedef type, which is defined as `T` if `B` is `true` at compile time, or as `F` if `B` is `false`.

Hence, the following would suffice;

```
typedef typename std::conditional<cond, int, double>::type Type;
```

Or the more terse;

```
using Type = std::conditional_t<cond, int, double>;
```

Comment: is it really not legal to use SFINAE with typedef, e.g. `template <typename T> class C { typedef std::enable_if<trait<T>::value, blah> type; };`?

Comment: Not really, see here; https://godbolt.org/g/2YT04Q. I've also not really seen it outside the immediate context of the template deduction. The issue is what happens when the condition is false, the typedef has no type to alias. SFINAE is used to deal with overload resolution of function templates, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <type_traits>

// c++11:
typedef typename std::conditional<cond, int, double>::type Type;

// c++14:
typedef std::conditional_t<cond, int, double> Type;
```

Also note that since c++11 you can use the [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) keyword for type and template aliases (a bit cleaner in my opinion):

```
// c++11
using Type = typename std::conditional<cond, int, double>::type;

// c++14
using Type = std::conditional_t<cond, int, double>;
```